rcptt 2.5.2 supporting till which eclipse version
Trying to upgrade eclipse version 4.23 to latest 4.27 but not able to understand about rcptt support with elcipse 4.27 Wanted to know what is last eclipse version rcptt 2.5.2 work
And what rcptt version 2.5.2 end the support of eclipse verion

The latest Eclipse version is 4.32, not 4.27. The latest and recommended RCPTT version is 2.5.4 which was already part of the Eclipse IDE 2023-03 release which contained the Eclipse Project 4.27.0 together with Eclipse RCP Testing Tool 2.5.4.

@howlger so for eclipse 4.27, we don't need to install rcptt plugin externally to write and test RCPTT testcase? is my understanding correct?
Thanks.
